# How to save a blob on mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i basically need to save a blob on a mongo database, on my back end i use node express / moongose as orm , im sending a audio blob to my back end i dont know what would be the best aproach to save this audio on my db, retrive later on my front end and play, i heard about grindfs, but that should only be used  for files bigger than 16 mb and this blob come from a 00:30 sec audio record.

thanks in advance guys... sorry for my english in advance...

[the schema where i need to save the blob on my back end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkKX9.png)

[blob coming from my back end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cDgQ.png)

i tried to generate a base64 string of that blob, but this return a huge string, and i dont think that is very performative just trhow that string on my database

i just need to save the audio as a blob on my db, retrieve on my front end and play the same audio

Comment: Not sure of the node equivalent, but in one of our applications where we save pdfs in groovy, we have the field as a Binary field, and we store the byte[] in it.  Node may have something similar.

Comment: Isn't easier to save audio file to hard drive sending it by multipart/form-data, and just save link of that file in database as string?
This module https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer can help you with handling multipart/form-data

Comment: @Deathmras, thank you very much for your reply, i couldnt exactly understand what you mean with save on the hard driver

Comment: @Taplar thank you very much for your reply, im trying this approach right now, save the entire blob on binary lets see if work out

Comment: @Deathmras the issue with saving the file to disk and then saving a reference to it in mongo, is that you've created two points of failure.  The file could be removed from the disk and mongo wouldn't know, and you could potentially remove the mongo reference and have a stranded file on disk.  Being able to store the blob in mongo allows for a single, self-contained, storage point that involves a single lookup to get the resource.